# Refreshing session of other servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, struts

I have a problem with handling sessions between Java servlet, jsp page and Struts Action. Java servlet adds some param to session when get request and sendRedirect to some page1.jsp. On page1 I have an url to Struts Action like strutsAction.do. When StrutsAction recevies request, the session doesn't contain attributes I added in Java servlet. Clicking on page returned by this action doesnt refresh session of Java Servlet, but they have the same SessionId. So, after `session.getMaxInactiveInterval()` of servlet session pass I'm getting `sessionDestroyed()` event, even when i taking actions on page returned by StrutsAction. [image] How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case of SendRedirect call old request and response object is lost because it’s treated as new request,

You should try the following code

```
RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

becuase when forward is called on requestdispather object we pass request and response object so our old request object is present on new resource which is going to process our request.